# Looking for an web based ftp client

Tags: web, ftp, ftp-client

I am looking for an truely "web based" (website) FTP client, to upload my html/web stuff.

What I found sofar is http://www.net2ftp.com/.
The site is a good example of what I am looking for, but isn't as usefull as I thought.

So, does anybody know a better site?

Answer (score 0):

There are many option available both on the server side (where the server does all the FTP traffic and shows it to the web browser and on the client side via Java Applet, ActiveX or Flash component)

Depending on what you need to do each option will have it's own advantages.

For example if you need to handle Folder Structures or multiple files then a client side Java Applet or ActiveX will be the best option.

If you only wish to handle a single file then the server side option will be better.

Start by searching for "ftp java applet" it will point you in the right direction.

I also compiled a Blog that tries to compare all your web based file transfer options

Here is the link:

http://www.filecatalyst.com/comparison-of-web-based-file-transfer-methodologies